# Delegating host in SSH file

Tags: ssh

I would like to "delegate" one host to another in my `.ssh/config` file, i.e., I would like the following:

```
ssh machine-a
```

...to use the configuration for `machine-b`.

Is there a way to do this?

---

I am using GCloud compute engine, and when I do a `gcloud compute config-ssh`, my `.ssh/config` file is updated with something like:

```
# Google Compute Engine Section
#
# The following has been auto-generated by "gcloud compute config-ssh"
# to make accessing your Google Compute Engine virtual machines easier.
#
# To remove this blob, run:
#
#   gcloud compute config-ssh --remove
#
# You can also manually remove this blob by deleting everything from
# here until the comment that contains the string "End of Google Compute
# Engine Section".
#
# You should not hand-edit this section, unless you are deleting it.
#
Host holt-vm.europe-west1-b.holt-project
    HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    IdentityFile /home/holt/.ssh/google_compute_engine
    UserKnownHostsFile=/home/holt/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts
    HostKeyAlias=compute.XXX
    IdentitiesOnly=yes
    CheckHostIP=no

# End of Google Compute Engine Section
```

So if I want to connect to my VM, I have to type:

```
ssh holt-vm.europe-west1-b.holt-project
```

...and I would like to only type `ssh holt-vm`.

I could change the `Host holt-vm.europe-west1-b.holt-project` to `Host holt-vm`, but I would have to edit the `.ssh/config` file each time I run `gcloud compute config-ssh` (which I have to run when I restart a VM).

Comment: Is the domain always "europe-west1-b.holt-project" ? Then you may add it in /etc/resolv.conf, in search parameter

Comment: @Dom Unfortunately I am on Windows, and on a Linux machine this would require privilege access I think?

Comment: Yes it will require privileges, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

> have to type:
>
> ```
>    ssh holt-vm.europe-west1-b.holt-project
> ```
>
> ...and I would like to only type `ssh holt-vm`

In your ~/.ssh/config you need to set two options:

`CanonicalDomains europe-west1-b.holt-project`  and
`CanonicalizeHostname yes` or `always`

With  probably  a longer  list with domain suffixes in which ssh has to search for the specified destination host.

> **`CanonicalizeHostname`**
>                Controls whether explicit hostname canonicalization is performed.  The default, no, is not to perform
>                any name rewriting and let the system resolver handle all hostname lookups.  If set to yes then, for
>                connections that do not use a ProxyCommand, ssh(1) will attempt to canonicalize the hostname specified
>                on the command line using the CanonicalDomains suffixes and CanonicalizePermittedCNAMEs rules.  If
>                CanonicalizeHostname is set to always, then canonicalization is applied to proxied connections too.
>     If this option is enabled, then the configuration files are processed again using the new target name to
>                pick up any new configuration in matching Host and Match stanzas.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work, I get the following error `ssh: Could not resolve hostname holt-vm: Name or service not known`.